# How to get 2 fragments of the same class with different content?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have class:

```
public class ConferenceListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(new DBHelper(getSherlockActivity()));       
        //How to get veriable "FLAG_BOOLEAN" ?
        List list = dbAdapter.getListItemInfoArray(FLAG_BOOLEAN);

        dbAdapter.close();

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
    }
}
```

Depending on the variable FLAG_BOOLEAN, i get different data from DB.
So can i send this FLAG from Activity to fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [setArguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) in the activity to pass them to the fragments and [getArguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29) from within the fragments to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the Fragments programmatically, you can add a constructor for ConferenceListFragment that takes in your boolean flag and add fragments using FragmentTransaction, like so:

```
ConferenceListFragment list1 = new ConferenceListFragment(true);
ConferenceListFragment list2 = new ConferenceListFragment(false);

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(parentView, list1);
ft.add(parentView, list2);
ft.commit();
```

With the constructor setting a private boolean member variable in ConferenceListFragment:

```
public ConferenceListFragment(boolean flag){
    this.flag = flag;
}
```

Then when you call your method, you can do:

```
List list = dbAdapter.getListItemInfoArray(this.flag);
```

Comment: I tried. Logcat wrote me that constructor must be empty. And so there was a question.

Comment: Ah. Robert Estivill's method is probably the preferred one then.